# How to make web page content scroll over a fixed header?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed `header` element which stays fixed to the top of the page when a user scrolls down. I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhs6h/) to demonstrate how this looks.

How can I make the `content` element scroll over the top of the `header` element instead of scrolling underneath? I tried adding `z-index: 99999;` to `content` but this had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor modification: add

```
z-index:-1;
```

to header { }

Comment: Thanks for the very simple solution! appreciated (apparently I can't accept until 7 minutes time)